# how can an "OR" be performed on an xpath expression without having to join two xpaths with a "|" or using an xpath function?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlnode

If I want to select /a/b1/c and /a/b2/c I can use one of the following:

```
  /a/*[local-name()='b1' or local-name()='b2']/c
  /a/b1/c | /a/b2/c
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to specify "b1 or b2" without having to retype almost the entire expression and without having to use the local-name function.

Unfortunately, these expressions don't work:

```
 /a/b1 or b2/c
 /a/[b1 or b2]/c
 /a/b1 | b2/c
 /a/[b1 | b2]/c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two XPath 1.0 solutions that are a bit shorter than your original, and don't rely on local-name() would be:

```
/a/*[self::b1 or self::b2]/c
/a/*[self::b1 | self::b2]/c
```

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2 you can use:

```
  /a/(b1|b2)/c
```

As well as

```
  /a/(b1,b2)/c
```